# How do I access my google plus content and the things that have been shared with me via the API

Tags: python, json, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I wish to get a listing of all my posts as well as of any and all shares sent to me on my Google+ page, I want to do that from a python script that has no html or other front end.However I am confused as to how I can get access to the content.
According to the google developers site I can not get an OAuth token for google plus if there isn't a graphical front end,, but I just want to get to my own stuff and do a bit of parsing.

Surely there must be a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Github repo](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-python) that can help you

- Using the Google+ Sign-In button to get an OAuth 2.0 refresh token.
- Exchanging the refresh token for an access token.
- Making Google+ API requests with the access token, including getting
  a list of people that the user has circled.
- Disconnecting the app from the user's Google account and revoking
  tokens.

Comment: Thank you, although this wasn't exactly what I wanted.I have no desire to interact with any web forms and et cetera, I just wanted a token that can let me parse my own content and the things that people share with me, preferably with a cron job that executes the script.Oh well, I guess I might try this.Again thank you

Comment: It does, and I did, but I am a new user and this site does not let me upvote without extra reputation :(